# WCF service with Restful API and circular reference issue

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

I have an object with design

```
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Entity : IEntity
    {
         .....
    }
```

When I set the IsReference = true, If I consume WCF service by Restful with json format, I will have an exception because the DataContractJsonSerializer does not support IsReference property.

If I remove the IsReference = true, when consuming WCF service by Restful with Json or consuming WCF service by WCF SOAP, The circular reference issue will be occured.

So how do I fix this issue?

---

#### Solved

I found out a workaround to replace the DataContractJsonSerializer with Newtonsoft JsonSerializer. It will resolve this issue.

I follow the article at https://itq.nl/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that the the standard Microsoft JSON serializers don't support it that scenario it is supported by Json.

Make the serialization handle self referencing objects like this:

WebAPI Rest Server:

Before deserializing, you may need to attach the below resolver to your settings:

```
 settings.ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver();
    public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var r = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            r.Ignored = false;
            return r;
        }
    }
```

And the client:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theObject, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize })
```

Moral: Do not use Micrososft JSON serializers.

Comment: I am using WCF Server with Restfull, so how I config the HttpConfiguration ?